# Replace * in string by character in c#. Example p**gra* replace * by rom the output will be program

Tags: c#

This is the code I'll try. But I got wrong output. Replace * in string by character in c#. Example p**gra* replace * by rom the output will be program.

```
namespace Uncensor
{
    class Program
    {

        // "*h*s *s v*ry *tr*ng*", "Tiiesae" ➜ "This is very strange"
        static string uncensor(string str,string s)
        {
            string s1 = "";
            int i, j;
            if (str.Contains("*"))
            {
               
               for (i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
               {
                    if (str[i] == '*')
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
                    {
                        
                            s1 = str.Replace(str[i], s[j]);
                        }
                    }
               }

                return s1;
            }
            else
            {
                return str;
            }
            
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter  string:");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter string to be replaced by * :");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

           string original_text= uncensor(str, s);
            Console.WriteLine(original_text);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a working solution or an explanation why yours does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with `linq`:

```cs
string a = "*h*s *s v*ry *tr*ng*";
string b = "Tiiesae";

int index = 0;
string c = new string(a.Select(x => x == '*' ? b[index++] : x).ToArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public string solve(string str, string s)
{
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(str[i] == '*') {
        str[i] = s[index];
        ++index;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Please do not just dump a pile of code. We expect good questions, then we should provide [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You have a syntax error. Please test your code before submitting it.